# Q_STATIC_ASSERT & Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X compilation problems on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: qt5

I develop and maintain a very large opengl application, written using qt library. I'm switching from qt 4 to qt 5. I downloaded the qt 5.0.0 Windows (8) Visual Studio 2010 precompiled package. Unfortunately I discovered that I get millions of OpenGL errors caused by the OpenGL ES 2 support provided by the precompiled package. So, I downloaded the source code and I recompiled qt using the -opengl desktop flag on the configure step (for further details on the problem please refer [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23499)). The opengl compiler errors disappear but I still have hundreds compiler errors everytime inside the Qt library itself there is a reference to two macros Q_STATIC_ASSERT and Q_STATIC_ASSERT_X.
The typical kind of errors i get are:
- error C2062: type 'void' unexpected
- error C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'

Some suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: I solved the issue. A colleague of mine in 2004 (two-thousand-four) defined inside our library a static_assert macro!!!!!!! Covering the new keyword introduced by the c++11 standard. I spent two days an half in pain before discovering it. I almost killed him….

Answer (score 0):

As described in the comment to the question I solved the issue by looking for redefinition of static_assert and commenting it.
In particular my code was using the VCGLib library wich was redefining the assert in base.h